# TextChanged event not available when using the User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a search User controller , and I wont to make textChanged event available when um using the User Controller

```
  <UserControl x:Class="VSOft.WpfControls.VSeachTextBox.VSearchTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VSOft.WpfControls.VSeachTextBox"
         xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:VSOft.WpfControls.Properties"
         xmlns:VFontAwsome="clr-namespace:VSOft.WpfControls.VFontAwsome"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="25" MouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown">
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="SearchText"
            Margin="0"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="" Height="25"
            GotFocus="SearchText_GotFocus"
            TextInput="SearchText_TextInput"
            TextChanged="SearchText_TextChanged" />
        <Label x:Name="SearchHelperLabel" Content="Search" Height="25" Foreground="#FF9E9292" GotFocus="SearchHelperLabel_GotFocus" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="SearchTextIcon" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="275,0,0,0" Height="25" Foreground="{x:Null}" GotFocus="SearchTextIcon_GotFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <VFontAwsome:VFontAwsome VForeground="{DynamicResource SideBar.Icon.Normal}" VFontSize="20" VFontsType="search" Height="25" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

This is my implementation . How to make Textchanged Event available when using the User Control ?

Comment: is your event not getting fired or do you want to call it from mainwindow??

Comment: Hi kyle it is triggering I want to call it from mainwindow . Thank you

Comment: Do you want to add different implementation to your function in mainwindow or use the existing one ? if you want to use the existing one then you can directly call the usercontrol events by creating it's object and accessing its property like `myUsercontrol.SearchText_GotFocus(this, null)`

Comment: @kyle How may I call myUsercontrol.SearchText_GotFocus(this, null) ? does it has to be inside a method?

Comment: yes the method from where you wish to call the usercontrol method.

Comment: @kyle How may I call the TextChanged Event? There s no relevant field to call that  method

Comment: you need to make that event public first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112130/discussion-between-kalanamith-and-kyle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is by using [RoutedEvent Handler delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) where you place a delegate in your usercontrol and then access it in the MainWindow

In your UserControl.xaml.cs

```
    public event RoutedEventHandler TestClick;

    void onSearchFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.TestClick != null)
        {
            this.TestClick(this, e);
        }
    }
```

and in xaml

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
        x:Name="SearchText"
        Margin="0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="" Height="25"
        GotFocus="onSearchFocus"
```

You can access this `TestClick` delegate in your mainwindow just like any other command and create it's navigation handler.

```
   <Grid>
        <my:UserControl x:Name="testcontrol" TestClick="mycommand_click"  />
    </Grid>
```